# Declared exceptions in Java interface from Kotlin

Tags: java, kotlin

I have a set of web services that are intercepted by an Aspect with @AfterThrowing. The implementations of the web services are done in Kotlin, but it is based on generated Java code.

So I have a Java interface, and a Kotlin class implementing the interface. When the code throws I want to generically throw the defined fault in the Java interface instead (SomeFault):

```
public SomeResponseType methodName() throws SomeFault
```

If everything was in Java it could be done rather easily like this:

```
MethodSignature methodSignature = (MethodSignature) joinPoint.getStaticPart().getSignature();
Class<? extends Exception>[] declaredExceptions = methodSignature.getExceptionTypes();
```

...and then just execute the constructor of `declaredExceptions[0]`

But when I do something similar in Kotlin it seems like I can't find the exceptions declared in the Java interface:

```
val declaredExceptions = methodSignature.exceptionTypes
```

... gives me an empty list

***question:*** How can I find the Exceptions declared in a java interface when intercepting a Kotlin class implementing that interface?

Comment: https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.jvm/-throws/index.html

Comment: the interface is in Java, not Kotlin. What I want is to figure out "SomeFault" from my post. The Implementation of the interface and the aspectJ Aspect is in Kotlin.

Comment: If I understand correctly, what you're examining is the signature of the method of the Kotlin subclass. So if you want it to have a declared thrown exception, use Throws. Otherwise, don't examine that method, but instead the overridden method of the Java interface

Comment: you are right, I found a solution now based on your anwser, I just assumed wrong that this works the same way in pure Java and in a Java/Kotlin mixed world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution based on JBs comment:

```
Class.forName(methodSignature.declaringType.genericInterfaces[0].typeName).declaredMethods
.filter { method -> method.name == methodSignature.name }
.forEach { method -> method.exceptionTypes[0] <executed>}
```